# Ways to increase performance of DataTable.Load()?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I currently use a custom CSV class from Codeproject to create a CSV object. I then use this to populate a DataTable. Under profiling this is taking more time than I would like and I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing it?

The CSV contains approximately 2,500 rows and 500 columns.

The CSV reader is from: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

```
StreamReader s = new StreamReader(confirmedFilePath);
CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(s, true);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(csv);
```

I came across a google search suggesting a DataAdapter, but it was only one reference to this? I searched further but didn't find any collaboration.

Comment: `Under profiling this is taking more time than I would like`. Don't profile when doing the operation. Profiling is very CPU, memory and IO intensive.

Comment: I appreciate that but it's all proportionate to the rest of the code. I know the code is running about 5-7 times slower... so I can work out how long the Load() function is taking without the profiler and it's still a little long.

Comment: You can use `Stopwatch` to time the function exactly.

Comment: Ok so I presume your suggestion is to use the profiler to find the slowEST parts and then use stopwatch to time the slowEST lines of code. I do know this is one of my bottlenecks, are there better ways of loading CSV data int oa datatable?

Comment: This is probably one of the fastest, but you can try different CSV parsers for speed.

Comment: Why you put CVS Data in datatable in the first place ? You wont to store it in a database or what ?

Answer (score 1):

CsvReader is fast and reliable, I almost sure you can't find anything faster (if there is at all) for reading CSV data.

Limitation comes from DataTable processing new data, 2500*500 thats qiute of amount. I think fastest way would be direct CsvReader->DataBase (ADO.NET) chain.

Answer (score 0):

Give [GenericParser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F) a try.

Comment: -1: Please don't post answers that just contain links. Links break. At least indicate or quote the portions of the page that answer the question, and tell the asker _why_ you think this page answers their question.

Answer (score 0):

Always use the `BeginLoadData()` and `EndLoadData()` when filling from databases, as they already enforce constraints by themselves - the only downside is that a CSV file obviously does not, so any exception is thrown only after the whole operation ends.

```
...
dt.BeginLoadData();
dt.Load(csv, LoadOption.Upsert);
dt.EndLoadData();
```

**EDIT:** Use the `LoadOption.Upsert` only if the `DataBase` is empty, or you don't want to preserve any previous changes to existing data - its even more faster that way.